# CodeBlocks is telling me error: no member named 'x' in 'class'

Tags: c++, class, object, codeblocks, header-files

I am currently learning about classes and objects in C++. I have written a source code and a header file in C++ in CodeBlocks. They are in the same folder on my Mac.

When I try to build and run either file, CodeBlocks tells me "error: no member named 'x' in 'class'".

A screenshot of the header file and source code, the error messages, and the project folder are below. How can I correct this so that the source code file runs and outputs?

**LipstickWarehouse2.h**

```cpp
#ifdef LIPSTICKWAREHOUSE2_H_INCLUDED
#define LIPSTICKWAREHOUSE2_H_INCLUDED

using namespace std;

enum Brand
{
    Mac,
    Glossier,
    EsteeLauder
};

enum Color
{
    red,
    pink,
    nude,
    black,
    brown,
    gold,
    silver,
    other
};

enum Formula
{
    matte,
    sheer,
    satin,
    glossy
};

class Lipstick
{
public:
    Brand Name;
    Color LipColor;
    Color Tube;
    Formula Effect;
    float Price;
    int Rating;
};

void reccomendation(string words)
{
    if (Rating <= 3)
    {
        cout << "I would rethink this lipstick!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "I would recommend this lipstick!" << endl;
    }
}

#endif // LIPSTICKWAREHOUSE2_H_INCLUDED
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "LipstickWarehouse2.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Lipstick FavBrand;
    FavBrand.Brand = Mac;
    FavBrand.Color = red;
    FavBrand.Formula = matte;
    FavBrand.Tube = black;
    FavBrand.Price = 19.00;
    FavBrand.Rating = 5;
    
    Lipstick WorBrand;
    WorBrand.Brand = Glossier;
    WorBrand.Color = other;
    WorBrand.Formula = sheer;
    WorBrand.Tube = other;
    WorBrand.Price = 18.00;
    WorBrand.Rating = 3;
    
    cout << "Buyer: Should I buy the " << FavBrand.Brand << FavBrand.Color << FavBrand.Formula << "lipstick?" << endl;
    cout << "Seller: " << FavBrand.reccomendation << endl;
    cout << "Buyer: Should I buy the " << WorBrand.Brand << WorBrand.Color << WorBrand.Formula << "lipstick?" << endl;
    cout << "Seller: " << WorBrand.reccomendation << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Errors**

```
Line 9: No member named 'Brand' in 'Lipstick'
Line 10: No member named 'Color' in 'Lipstick'
Line 11: No member named 'Formula' in 'Lipstick'
Line 17: No member named 'Brand' in 'Lipstick'
Line 18: No member named 'Color' in 'Lipstick'
Line 19: No member named 'Formula' in 'Lipstick'
Line 24: No member named 'Brand' in 'Lipstick'
Line 24: No member named 'Color' in 'Lipstick'
Line 24: No member named 'Formula' in 'Lipstick'
Line 24: Reference to non-static member function must be called
Line 26: No member named 'Brand' in 'Lipstick'
Line 26: No member named 'Color' in 'Lipstick'
Line 26: No member named 'Formula' in 'Lipstick'
Line 27: Reference to non-static member function must be called
```

**Project folder**

*Ed. Note: ".cbp" is not a typo. See See [original image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo4Z6.png))

```
> bin
LipstickWarehouse2.cbp
LipstickWarehouse2.h
main.cpp
> obj
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.

Comment: As a general style guide, it's helpful if your capitalization distinguishes between types and values.  So, if your class names and functions begin with a capital letter, consider making your variable names begin with a lowercase letter at the very least.

Comment: What the heck is a ".cbp" file?

Comment: @Casey CodeBlocks Project?

Comment: @PaulSanders Well that's not going to be confusing at all between .cpp and .cbp in a tiny font.

Comment: @Casey Point taken.

Comment: It's probably a helpful clue that the compiler complains about `Brand`, `Color`, and `Formula`, but it has no issue with `Tube`, `Price`, and `Rating`. This is a sort of thing you should notice when debugging. This should tell you to stare at your class definition until you see what makes, for example, `Color` different than `Tube`.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears because you're trying to access class members by their types (Brand, Color, etc.) instead of names (Name, LipColor, ...)

Change your code in main() like this:

```
Lipstick FavBrand;
FavBrand.Name = Mac;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Lipstick
{
public:
    Brand Name;
    Color LipColor;
    Color Tube;
    Formula Effect;
    float Price;
    int Rating;
};
```

Here you declare a member named `Name` which has type `Brand`. To access this, you need to do

```
    Lipstick FavBrand;
    FavBrand.Name = Mac;
```

Notice that we use `Name` here instead of `Brand` because `Name` is the name of the member whereas `Brand` is its type. Accessing all other members needs to use their names rather than their types.